# android platform screen resolutions

Tags: android

How does android platform handle different types of screen resolutions ? platform takes that work how does it actualy work?

Answer (score 5):

Google has documented this part *extremely* well. Look at it here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: In that document it always says that platform takes care of adapting the application on two different screens but in that doucment it didnt mention how is it doing ?? if you find please tell me ..

Comment: Look at the link above, if you read it in detail, following all links in that page, you will find the answer. I android, asset handling is done based on screen density, screen size AND a definite hierarchy of how assets folders in res directory are parsed. It takes time but reading through this will clear all your doubts, so that.

Comment: i have read that but in the whole doucment it says that platform automatically scales to different resolutions.but how it is done please tell me.